# I have send custom mail and set the custom variable but. When I access the variable in transaction mail template then it will not work

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, variables, rma

This is my email sending code

```
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $templateId = 9;
    $sendername = 'Call To Order';
    $senderemail = $_POST['email'];
    $sendermobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $sender = Array('name' => $sendername,
        'email' => $senderemail);
    //recepient
    $toEmail = 'test@gmail.com';
    $vars = Array();
    $vars = Array('email' => $senderemail, 'mobile' => $sendermobile);
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
    Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
            ->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $toEmail, $vars, $storeId);
    $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
}
?>
```

this is my transnational email template

```
Email: {{var email}}

Mobile: {{var mobile}}
```

And I am getting this into my email

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below definition of *sendTransactional* method :

```
/**
 * Send transactional email to recipient
 *
 * @param   int $templateId
 * @param   string|array $sender sneder informatio, can be declared as part of config path
 * @param   string $email recipient email
 * @param   string $name recipient name
 * @param   array $vars varianles which can be used in template
 * @param   int|null $storeId
 * @return  Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template
 */
public function sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $name, $vars=array(), $storeId=null)
```

As you can see *$vars* is fifth parameter.

You code should looks like that :

```
Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
        ->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $toEmail, 'recipient name' $vars, $storeId);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to allow your variables :

```
System -> Permissions -> Variables -> Add new Variable
```